# Why isn't my AlertDialog working?

Tags: android, android-emulator

```
public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message, Boolean status) {

    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle(title);

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage(message);

    if(status != null)
        // Setting alert dialog icon
        alertDialog.setIcon((status) ? R.drawable.success : R.drawable.fail);
```

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting ? Just copy paste the error from LogCat.

Comment: What is the "error" you have. Edit your question.

Comment: Post the error...!!!!!!! Is it not working or are you getting an exception..?

Comment: Your subject MUST me according to question . Not like  "could any one please help me to find out the error in the below code.Thanks in advance"

Comment: ***could any one please help me to understand the above code.Thanks in advance.***

Comment: I've edited the title to improve it slightly, but as the OP hasn't clarified exactly what the problem is, I've left it still slightly vague.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said what isn't working, but I'm guessing the dialog isn't appearing.

You need to call `alertDialog.show()` once you've finished building it.

Comment: most probable issue, and solution.

Comment: could u tell me clearly.

Comment: how is that not clear? just call the d*** alertDialog.show() to _show_ it, as clearly stated in the *documentation*

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to find out your error without LogCat or something like that. You can see the way to use AlertDialog :

```
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            context);

        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, close
                    // current activity
                    MainActivity.this.finish();
                }
              })
            .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();
```

This example informs how to use AlertDialog in Android :
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-alert-dialog-example/

Comment: thanks for ur response, the problem occurs exactly in the line alertDialog.setIcon((status) ? R.drawable.success:R.drawable.fail);

Comment: I get an error on the line "alertDialog.setIcon((status) ? R.drawable.success : R.drawable.fail);" as well. It says "success cannot be resolved or is not a field" and same for fail

Comment: You should check success icon that is exist or not.